# Get changed in WinForms RichTextBox.TextChanged like WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, richtextbox

In WPF [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx).TextChanged I have [TextChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textchangedeventargs.aspx) with [Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textchangedeventargs.changes.aspx) (a collection of objects that contains information about the changes that occurred). But WinForms [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx).TextChanged is EventHandler with usual EventArgs. How I can changes list in WinForms?

Comment: Trying to get WPF features from winforms is like trying to get Samsung's S4 features from a Nokia 1100. Your best option here is to use the `ElementHost` and host a WPF RichTextBox in an (existing?) winforms application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the winforms event only signals the change, not what changed.

One solution would be to store the content of the textbox in a variable when populated, then compare this against the current data in the textbox on the event firing (also updating the stored variable to not catch changes twice etc)